# How to prove that this function is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

My problem is that: 
The domain is $\mathbb{R} ^n _{++}$ .
I need to prove that $f(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\cdot ln(x_i) -(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)\cdot ln(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i) $
is convex.

I tried to use the Jensen inequality but it is not working.
Also I try to prove it by induction on the length of x in $\mathbb{R} ^n _{++}$ and it does not working.

Comment: also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409322/convexity-of-combination-of-natural-logs-with-sums-function/3414364

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is $-1$ times what is referred to as the 'normalised entropy of $x$'. One way to show its convex is expressing it as the perspective of a convex function as in example 3.19 of [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).