# How to prove this function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I should prove this function is convex over $\mathbb R_{++}^n$,:
$$f(X) = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\ln(x_i) - (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)(\ln(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i))$$
where X is of form $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ .

That's not easy to prove it using a second derivative (almost impossible), so I tried to prove it using this lemma:
$$f(\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2) \leq \lambda f(X_1) + (1-\lambda) f(X_2)$$
I think this won't be very easy to calculate, so maybe there's a more straightforward way to prove that. Does anybody know what to do with this?

Comment: Hi :) What is the problem with the second derivative?

Comment: @Jochen Hi there. We have n parameters. Think of the resulting Hessian-Matrix

Comment: doesn't it work fine using the concavity of $\ln$ and maybe the convexity of $x^2$ (and jensen for a convex combination of $n$ terms) ? I haven't tried it though.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3409322/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383836/42969